# style.display = 'block' not working in javascript on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to Add a DIV which has a image source in it to an HTML. and after i am trying to change the property of above added DIV. But i am not able to do so. The DIV is showing up in the Browser Development tools when checked. The Error i am getting is "Cannot read property 'style' of null". Below is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
ajaxLoaddiv='<div class="LoadingImage" alt="example" style="display: none"> <img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"></div>';
$(ajaxLoaddiv).appendTo(attachPoint);
document.getElementById("LoadingImage").style.display = 'block';
```

attachpoint is a reference in the html which i got by.

```
var attachpoint=document.querySelector('.buttonAttachPoint');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` gets the element by ID, not class?

```
var ajaxLoaddiv = $('<div />', {'class': 'LoadingImage',
                                 alt   : 'example',
                                 style : 'display: none'
                                }),
    img = $('<img />', {src: 'css/ajax-loader.gif'});

ajaxLoaddiv.append(img).appendTo(attachPoint);
ajaxLoaddiv.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You gave it `class='LoadingImage'`, but not `id='LoadingImage'` and later attempt to retrieve it with `getElementById("LoadingImage")`. Just add the `id` attribute.

```
ajaxLoaddiv='<div id="LoadingImage" class="LoadingImage" alt="example" style="display: none"> <img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"></div>';
//--------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But if you are already using jQuery, you might as well use it here too.

```
$('#LoadingImage').css('display', 'block');
```

...And could therefore more easily access it by class (assuming this is the only element with the class `LoadingImage`) if you prefer:

```
$('.LoadingImage').css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$("#LoadingImage").css({"display": "block"});
```

If you want a jQuery solution :)

Also, you used a class name instead of the element's ID